# Informatica - trial version?

Tags: data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have heard that informatica power center tool is a licensed software. I would like to know whether the free trial version of informatica 8.6 is avaialable? If so, anybody pls share the URL which has the correct installation procedure. Whether I will be able to install trail version once again when the trial version date expires?

Answer (score 4):

[PowerCenter Express](https://community.informatica.com/solutions/pcexpress) may be what you are looking for. It's a free version of PowerCenter intended for small projects. It has many limitations (250K rows per day, single user, one job at a time) but it will allow you to evaluate the tool.